# Airflow accessing command line arguments in Dag definition

Tags: airflow

I am trying to access the argument passed to the Dag through rest API in the Dag definition like below and I am passing config_path and s3_bucket as an argument in Rest API and wants to capture them in the custom `SparkLivyOperator`. `SparkLivyOperator` reads all the arguments and launches a Spark job on EMR. I tried reading these arguments as below but I dont get any values.

Below is my curl command:

```
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:8080/api/experimental/dags/**spark_launcher**/dag_runs \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{"conf":"{\"s3_bucket\":\"--s3_bucket s3://test_bucket/\", \"config_path\":\"--config_path this_is_conf\"}"}'
```

```
config_path='{{ dag_run.conf["config_path"] }}',
s3_bucket='{{ dag_run.conf["s3_bucket"] }}
```

Below is my Dag definition:

```
import os
from datetime import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from EmrManagerOperator import EmrManagerOperator

DEFAULT_ARGS = {
    'owner': 'hadoop',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2021, 8, 1, 0),
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'schedule_interval': None,
    'retries': 2
}

DOCKER_RELEASE_VERSION = '0.1.0-38'  # this python3 emr-5.23.0 release
STAGE = os.environ['STAGE']
ENV = STAGE.lower()
REGION = 'na'
COUNTRIES = 'US'
DAG_UUID = 'TestDag'
# EMR EC2 instance related variables
EMR_RELEASE_VERSION = 'emr-5.29.0'
EC2_INSTANCE_TYPE = 'r4.4xlarge'
EC2_INSTANCE_COUNT = '3'
EC2_INSTANCE_VOLUME_SIZE = '500'
DOCKER_IMAGE = '833176741232.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/emr-manager:' + DOCKER_RELEASE_VERSION
BOOTSTRAP_SCRIPT = 's3://bucket/scripts/install-basic-python-aws-cli-libs.sh'


def get_emr_id(context):
    """
    Get EMR cluster ID from context
    :param context: context of instance of task
    :return: emr_id: str  cluster_id of emr cluster
    """
    emr_info = context['task_instance'].xcom_pull(task_ids='emr-create-{dag_id}'.format(dag_id=DAG_UUID))
    print(emr_info)
    return emr_info["cluster_id"]


def get_emr_dns(context):
    """
    Function to get emr dns
    :param context: airflow context
    :return: str: emr dns
    """
    emr_info = context['task_instance'].xcom_pull(task_ids='emr-create-{dag_id}'.format(dag_id=DAG_UUID))
    print(emr_info)
    return emr_info["emr_master_dns"]


with DAG(dag_id=DAG_UUID, default_args=DEFAULT_ARGS, schedule_interval=None, max_active_runs=10) as dag:
    emr_manager_create_task = EmrManagerOperator(
        dag=dag,
        job_name='emr-create-{dag_id}'.format(dag_id=DAG_UUID),
        region=REGION,
        image=DOCKER_IMAGE,
        emr_action='create_emr',
        emr_instance_profile="EMR-InstanceRole",
        emr_cluster_name="emr-on-demand-cluster-na",
        emr_release_label=EMR_RELEASE_VERSION,
        emr_node_instance_type=EC2_INSTANCE_TYPE,
        emr_master_instance_type=EC2_INSTANCE_TYPE,
        emr_bootstrap_script_path=BOOTSTRAP_SCRIPT,
        emr_node_volume_size=EC2_INSTANCE_VOLUME_SIZE,
        emr_node_on_demand_count=EC2_INSTANCE_COUNT,
        project='di2-etl',
        env=ENV)

    segment_release_task = SparkLivyOperator(
        dag=dag,
        jobName=DAG_UUID,
        task_id='livy_operator_task.' + DAG_UUID,
        region=REGION,
        get_emr_dns=get_emr_dns,
        env=ENV,
        stage=STAGE,
        **config_path='{{ dag_run.conf["config_path"] }}',
        s3_bucket='{{ dag_run.conf["s3_bucket"] }}'**
    )

    emr_manager_delete_task = EmrManagerOperator(
        dag=dag,
        job_name='emr-delete-{dag_id}'.format(dag_id=DAG_UUID),
        region=REGION,
        image=DOCKER_IMAGE,
        emr_action='delete_emr',
        get_emr_id=get_emr_id,
        trigger_rule="all_done",
        env=ENV
    )

    emr_manager_create_task >> segment_release_task >> emr_manager_delete_task
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have not marked parameters as "templated" parameters. When you define your Custom Operator, you can add the fields to "template_fields" static field:

```
    template_fields = ['s3_bucket', 'config_path']
```

Only fields which are added to template_fields are processed by JINJA templating.

Comment: Thanks Jarek for you answer, let me try this.